# Flattening JSON with schema changes in a single JSON object

Tags: azure-data-factory, genesys

I am new to ADF and looking to flatten the data of a complex JSON object. The JSON comes in from Genesys API endpoint. Although Genesys has defined a response schema, there is no guarantee that all the keys defined in the schema will be part of the response JSON. Following is an example of the JSON object with a different set of keys. I have replaced identifiable information with "hidden" for relevant keys.

```
{
            "conversationEnd": "2022-03-20T18:53:14.696Z",
            "conversationId": "hidden",
            "conversationStart": "2022-03-20T18:52:43.441Z",
            "divisionIds": [
                "hidden"
            ],
            "mediaStatsMinConversationMos": 4.882435906757346,
            "mediaStatsMinConversationRFactor": 92.44477081298828,
            "originatingDirection": "inbound",
            "participants": [
                {
                    "participantId": "hidden",
                    "participantName": "hidden",
                    "purpose": "external",
                    "sessions": [
                        {
                            "ani": "hidden",
                            "direction": "inbound",
                            "dnis": "hidden",
                            "edgeId": "hidden",
                            "mediaType": "voice",
                            "protocolCallId": "hidden",
                            "provider": "Edge",
                            "recording": true,
                            "remoteNameDisplayable": "hidden",
                            "sessionDnis": "hidden",
                            "sessionId": "hidden",
                            "mediaEndpointStats": [
                                {
                                    "codecs": [
                                        "audio/opus"
                                    ],
                                    "eventTime": "2022-03-20T18:53:14.724Z",
                                    "maxLatencyMs": 30,
                                    "minMos": 4.882435906757346,
                                    "minRFactor": 92.44477081298828,
                                    "receivedPackets": 950
                                }
                            ],
                            "metrics": [
                                {
                                    "emitDate": "2022-03-20T18:52:55.715Z",
                                    "name": "nConnected",
                                    "value": 1
                                }
                            ],
                            "segments": [
                                {
                                    "conference": false,
                                    "segmentEnd": "2022-03-20T18:52:55.715Z",
                                    "segmentStart": "2022-03-20T18:52:43.442Z",
                                    "segmentType": "system"
                                },
                                {
                                    "conference": false,
                                    "disconnectType": "endpoint",
                                    "q850ResponseCodes": [
                                        16
                                    ],
                                    "segmentEnd": "2022-03-20T18:53:14.695Z",
                                    "segmentStart": "2022-03-20T18:52:55.715Z",
                                    "segmentType": "interact"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "participantId": "hidden",
                    "purpose": "hidden",
                    "userId": "hidden",
                    "sessions": [
                        {
                            "ani": "hidden",
                            "direction": "inbound",
                            "dnis": "",
                            "edgeId": "hidden",
                            "mediaType": "voice",
                            "peerId": "",
                            "protocolCallId": "hidden",
                            "provider": "hidden",
                            "remote": "hidden",
                            "sessionDnis":"hidden",
                            "sessionId": "hidden",
                            "metrics": [
                                {
                                    "emitDate": "2022-03-20T18:52:55.468Z",
                                    "name": "tAlert",
                                    "value": 12000
                                }
                            ],
                            "segments": [
                                {
                                    "conference": false,
                                    "disconnectType": "noAnswerTransfer",
                                    "segmentEnd": "2022-03-20T18:52:55.468Z",
                                    "segmentStart": "2022-03-20T18:52:43.468Z",
                                    "segmentType": "alert"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "participantId": "hidden",
                    "purpose": "hidden",
                    "userId": "hidden",
                    "sessions": [
                        {
                            "ani": "hidden",
                            "direction": "hidden",
                            "dnis": "hidden",
                            "edgeId": "hidden",
                            "mediaType": "hidden",
                            "peerId": "hidden",
                            "protocolCallId": "hidden",
                            "provider": "hidden",
                            "remote": "hidden",
                            "sessionDnis": "hidden",
                            "sessionId": "hidden",
                            "metrics": [
                                {
                                    "emitDate": "2022-03-20T18:53:14.696Z",
                                    "name": "tVoicemail",
                                    "value": 19022
                                }
                            ],
                            "segments": [
                                {
                                    "conference": false,
                                    "segmentEnd": "2022-03-20T18:52:55.674Z",
                                    "segmentStart": "2022-03-20T18:52:55.518Z",
                                    "segmentType": "system"
                                },
                                {
                                    "conference": false,
                                    "disconnectType": "peer",
                                    "q850ResponseCodes": [
                                        16
                                    ],
                                    "segmentEnd": "2022-03-20T18:53:14.696Z",
                                    "segmentStart": "2022-03-20T18:52:55.674Z",
                                    "segmentType": "interact"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
```

The data flow is unable to create a projection for the above JSON. Could any of you please help?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using Flatten Transformation in Mapping data flow.

> Use the flatten transformation to take array values inside
> hierarchical structures such as JSON and unroll them into individual
> rows. This process is known as denormalization.

To handle data which is not compulsorily available in the file, use `Unroll by` feature. This will select an array to unroll. The output data will have one row per item in each array. **If the unroll by array in the input row is null or empty, there will be one output row with unrolled values as null.**

Refer this [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-flatten) to learn more and refer the given example to accomplish the flatten transformation.

Comment: Hi Utkarsh! Thank you for the reply. Unfortunately, the "Unroll by" and "Unroll root" are not displaying any options.

Comment: which Linked Service and Dataset you are using?

Comment: Dataset type: JSON, Dataset source location - BLOB, Linked Service: Azure Blob Storage

Comment: Open the debug mode for your data flow. Once your ingest the data from source, check in "Data previews" if it is loaded or not.

Comment: I did try that. I did not load the preview.

Comment: It should load the data, then only you can apply flatten transformation.

Comment: Yep, that's the exact problem that I am facing :(

Comment: have you checked your connection with Blob storage while creating Linked Service? Also make sure you have defined the correct file (should be available in destination container in storage) in dataset.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243675/discussion-between-novice-dev-and-utkarshpal-mt).